# Generating form from json in meteor

Tags: json, meteor

I have uploaded 2 json files in temporary folder of meteor app.I want to create a form by using any json file (both have different fields).

I am already using autoform but it is creating form by json in static form in its js file.How can I do the same dynamically?

```
[
  "name",
  "email",
  {
    "key": "comment",
    "type": "textarea",
    "placeholder": "Make a comment"
  },
  {
    "type": "submit",
    "style": "btn-info",
    "title": "OK"
  }
]
```

Comment: Well, you could map the JSON to a `simpleSchema` and then be able to use it with `autoform`. With a bit more data (specifically a simple replica of the JSON) I think I could come up with something. Have you tried anything in this direction?

Comment: How can I map it , I  tried autoform. it saves the schema is js file, I dont want to do that, any other way?